# ASP.NET Core JSON-RPC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, json-rpc

I've created core WebAPI project and while RESTing performs quite good, there's also a need in JSON-RPC functionality. 
I saw things like [this](https://github.com/alexanderkozlenko/aspnetcore-json-rpc) or [this](https://github.com/edjCase/JsonRpc), but still don't know which one of them is preferred for organizing server and client(which is aspnetcore too) as good replacement of something like WCF.

So how to do JSON-RPC with ASP.NET Core in the right way?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a great example from James Newton-King.

`Newtonsoft.Json` creator made a project that works great with gRPC and ASP.NET.

Check here:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/master/src/GrpcHttpApi

And an example from the readme:

Usage:

- Add a package reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Grpc.HttpApi.
- Register services in Startup.cs with `AddGrpcHttpApi()`.
- Add google/api/http.proto and google/api/annotations.proto files to your project.
- Annotate gRPC methods in your .proto files with HTTP bindings and routes:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/api/annotations.proto";

package greet;

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/v1/greeter/{name}"
    };
  }
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

The SayHello gRPC method can now be invoked as gRPC+Protobuf and as an HTTP API:

Comment: while this is interesting, link-only answers are discouraged, as the links can become invalid, and so will the whole answer. Consider incoporating some summary information to answer the question, and / or quote relevant parts from the source in the answer itself.

Comment: I will edit the answer. But with the logic you mentioned, even if I will put the code here, the github repo can be deleted and also the nuget package so this code will become useless.

Comment: of course, adding info to use a package does not prevent the package from disappearing. This policy is not _sufficient_ to prevent an answer become invalid, but link-roting is something very common, and thus forbidding link-only answers has become a policy on Stack Overflow. As an example, many links to old microsoft doc are now invalid. However, everything (languages, framework, packages) is still working. See for instance this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) for more insight.